# how to locate the map based on fetched latitude and longitude using google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps

i have used placeAPI to fetch the latitude and longitude and trying to bind that with the map, but i am getting issue as Cannot find gmapElement of null. I am here by pasting my demo.

Here, i have used placesAPI to fetch lat and lon value, and i am assigning those values as lat and lon, but i want these lat and lon values also to fetch the lat and lon value via the address given.

TS:

```
var map = new window['google'].maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
  center: {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195},
  zoom: 8
});
var request = {
  query:geoAddress,
  fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
};
```

Error:

```
Cannot read property 'gmapElement' of null
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row mt-5" [hidden]="!map">
                            <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
                                <h2 class="text-left">Google Map</h2>
                                <div class="card mt-3">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div #mapRef style="width:100%;height:400px"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yp9cxx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Where do you create the `gmapElement`?

Comment: Hi @geocodezip i have updated the code, and in demo detailed code is there.

Comment: have you added google api key in index page like <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY"></script>

Comment: Hi @HiteshKansagara, you mean in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved your issue. and created demo please check it and verify. your this scope inside the service.findPlaceFromQuery() function changed so you are getting that error.

[Resolved Issue Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xzh5t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)